# Collect time and params for each step of each build

Tags: jenkins, metrics

in my company we are using Jenkins pipelines and we would like to collect metrics about the time needed for each step of the pipeline in order to measure performance improvements introduced by changes.

We have many different pipelines, each pipeline has several steps (from 5 to 15 steps), we would like to know for each step of each pipeline

1. Name of the step and the pipeline
2. How much time the step required for each run
3. The parameters used in the specific pipeline run (e.g. in some pipelines we can enable only a subset of feature and this may affect some of the stages, like the setup)

I found several APIs which can provide these information e.g.

1. [https://jenkins.example.com/api/json?tree=jobs[name]](https://jenkins.example.com/api/json?tree=jobs%5Bname%5D)
2. https://jenkins.example.com/job/<job_name>/<run_number>/api/json
3. https://jenkins.example.com/job/<job_name>/wfapi/runs

but this means to iterate over #1 to retrieve all pipelines, iterate over #2 to retrieve all runs (with params) or each pilines for each run and finally iterate over #3 to retrieve all stages with time.

Does it exist and API which may provide all runs with stages and params for each run of each pipeline? Or even a plugin which may provides these information may be fine, provided that I can still add some additional data before storing in a DB.

Edit: I checked also Blue Ocean APIs but it seems that they will return more or less same information I will get from Jenkins itself: so I will have all information but I have to either use a triple loop (and a lot of requests) or change the logic (e.g. modify each pipeline to collect and send its information).

Answer (score 0):

Your second option makes more sense (modify each pipeline to collect and send its information). To prevent code duplication, create a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) with a function to collect the information and send it. You can then import this shared library to your pipelines and use its function within a stage. Any time you need to change the functionality of your code, you can just change the shared library and the changes will propagate to the pipelines that your code is used in.